# convert to users correct timezone

Tags: php, mysql, timezone, timestamp

I am storing my dates in my database with php date(); then I am querying the date and converting it to a readable format I need to get the users timezone then add or subtract to the correct time. and I have been working on this for too long and I need help lol. my database variable is $datep

```
$dateTime1 = new DateTime($datep);
$dateq81 = $dateTime1->format('g:i A');
$dateq61 = new DateTime($todaysdate);
$dateq51 = $dateq61->format('g:i A');
$dateTime = new DateTime($datep);
$dateq8 = $dateTime->format('g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');
$dateq6 = new DateTime($todaysdate);
$dateq5 = $dateq6->format('g:ia \o\n l jS F Y');
$dateTime2 = new DateTime($datep);
$dateq82 = $dateTime2->format('jS M Y');
$dateq62 = new DateTime($todaysdate);
$dateq52 = $dateq62->format('jS M Y');
list($hh,$mm,$ss)= split(':',$dateq81);
if ($dateq82 == $dateq52)
{
  $uploaddate = 'Today at '.$dateq81.'';
    }
else
{
   $uploaddate = $dateq8;
}
```

I have been playing around with this

```
$timestamp = strtotime($datep) - (540*60);
```

which I think would help but no luck so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime constructor parameter to pass the time zone and PHP will do it for you so need to do arithmetic by yourself.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Comment: I'm sure you right just need to read more up on it I guess because I don't understand yet.

Comment: @NatoThorpe Let me know if you have any questions. Basically you would have to store the name of the timezone for every user (e.g. "Europe/London") and just pass it.